# I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.
>
> My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.
>
> I don't work night shifts or sleep.
>
> I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.
>
> People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.
>
> My living conditions are pitiful.

*What am I?*

Good luck guys! If you could leave a rating out of 10 for how difficult this was, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> Public transfer (specific a bus)

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.

> Millions of people use public transfer every day, and it is considered to be "normal"

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> A bus is a way of traveling, with his friend the driver

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> On average a bus doesnt drive at night

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> The bus has a lot of stops, and can leave when the schedule let them.

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> People depend on the bus for work/school, but the bus isnt speeding because of it (or getting stressed by it in any other way)

My living conditions are pitiful.

> A bus is always loaded with people walking in and out. Often a messy place.

Comment: Exceptionally close! Great answer, Fearsome Statue. You're not far off, think about it a bit more. The 4th line is quite important.

Comment: Who is the one that doesn't take it for granted?

Comment: Isn't there overnight public transportation? Aren't there more than one bus driver? The rest of the answers line up to me, but these ones don't... but I see that it is an accepted answer...

Comment: I must say that an awful lot of this seems to me not to work. Lots of people don't take buses for granted. Buses may have multiple drivers and sometimes other people working on them. They often run at night, and if they don't they spend their nights in a depot turned off, which seems close enough to sleeping for me given the rest of the anthropomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

My answer

> The armed forces

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.

> Yeah, that is sadly true..

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> The gun and the soldier. Soldiers also get transferred from one region to another

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> A soldier stays awake so that we can sleep in peace

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> Shifts of soldiers, I guess..

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> A soldier does his job silently and never worries.

My living conditions are pitiful.

> Yes, sometimes living at below -4 celsius while sometimes above 45 celsius without any complaints

Comment: Let us have a moment of silence for our dear soldiers... :'(

Comment: "I don't work night shifts or sleep." soldiers regularly do 'night-shifts'.

Answer (score 4):

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.

> Cars

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> A car (generally) has one owner who frequently uses it.

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> Most commuter travel is during the day.

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> A car (generally) has long breaks during the day between use.

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> People heavily depend on their cars for travel.  A car has no ability to feel emotions.

My living conditions are pitiful.

> A car is extremely fortunate if its owner follows its maintenance schedule.  It is lucky to even get regular oil changes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Chappals or sandals

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.
My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> People always wear sandals while going outside

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> On average people sleep at night. So they do not wear sandals at night time

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> People left their sandals while entering into house, room etc..,

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> People depend on sandals for walking. Sandals have no stress feeling, because they are non- living beings

My living conditions are pitiful.

> They always stayed outside or in chappal stand

Comment: This answer makes sense, but it doesn't explain how the sandals use up their 'breaks' fully.

Comment: I will work more on your question..

Comment: @danilo restating the answer which was in spooler tags, is unhelpful to other people trying to answer the puzzle. Please remove the direct reference to the subject of the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are

> stairs

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.

> Lots of people use stairs without further thinking about them

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> `sole` companion, get it?

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> Stairs "work" all the time

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> Each single step is kind of a break in the stairs

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> People need stairs to go up and down and stairs cannot be stressed

My living conditions are pitiful.

> People step on stairs all the time

Comment: It says "my sole companion and _I_," and stairs don't travel much.

Comment: I see. I thought that was some kind of wordplay on shoes' soles.

Answer (score 1):

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.

> Heart. If it dies only one person will directly miss it.

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.

> Living people, when contrasted with the dead, constantly move/travel. 
> A living person must, therefore, travel with their heart.

I don't work night shifts or sleep.

> The heart doesn't work night shifts it works 24 hours a day & it doesn't sleep.

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.

> The heart takes a break between each beat.

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.

> The heart doesn't have emotions.

My living conditions are pitiful.

> Captivity and darkness ...

Answer (score 0):

I am...a sniffer dog.

I help millions of people every day, but am taken for granted by all but one.
  I keep millions of travelers safe, but my handler is the only one who loves me.

My sole companion and I are frequent travelers.
   My handler & I travel every day.

I don't work night shifts or sleep.
   Daytime is prime time for terrorists.
   Oh, dang! Some will say that I *do* sleep.  Nah, just resting my eyes.

I have several breaks, all of which I use up fully.
   I needs lots of breaks, but I use them for "personal business."  'Nuff said.

People depend on me, but I never get stressed by it.
   Stress?  hah!  I *live* for challenge.

My living conditions are pitiful.
   Really. A crate? At least I should have my own couch. And a down comforter.       And my the companionship of my favorite corgi-girl.

(Please forgive the mistake from a brand spankin' new newbie")

Comment: Next time, please make use of the Spoilers input method to hide your answer in case you spoil it for someone else. :)

Answer (score -1):

> Sun. doesn't do night shifts and never sleeps. sole companion is the moon?